# How to remove RequestTimeTooSkewed check from Amazon?

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, java-7

I have a Java 7 "agent" program running on several client machines (mostly Windows XP). My "agent" uploads client files to Amazon S3 and often I get this error:

RequestTimeTooSkewed

I know this is because the client's computer system time difference is too large compared to Amazon's. Here's my problem: I can't control the client's computer (system) time! So, I don't want Amazon to care about time differences.

I heard about jets3t, but I'm hoping not having to resort to yet another tool (agent footprint must remain small).

Any ideas how to remove this check and get rid of this pesky error?

Error detail:
Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 59C9614D15006F23, AWS Error Code: RequestTimeTooSkewed, AWS Error Message: The difference between the request time and the current time is too large., S3 Extended Request ID: v1pGBm3ed2J9dZ3sG/3aDrG3DUGSlt3Ac+9nduK2slih2wyaAnc1n5Jrt5TkRzlV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is coming from the S3 service, not from the client, so there really isn't anything you can do other than correct the clock on the client.  That check is being done on the service to help detect and prevent replay attacks so it's an important part of the overall security of the service.

Trying a different client-side SDK won't help.